# unicode-math breaks \DeclareMathOperator

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, unicode-math

## Problem Statement

I'd like to introduce a new math operator (the divergence operator). Unfortunately the macro I'd like to use is already defined, so I "free" it using

```
\let\div\undefined
```

and declare the new operator

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\div}{div}
```

If I am using only `amsmath` everything works fine, but as soon as I add `unicode-math` everything breaks.

## Implementation

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\let\div\undefined
\DeclareMathOperator{\div}{div}
\begin{document}
\[ \int_V \div \vec{F} \, \mathrm{d}V = \oint_A \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} \, \mathrm{d}A \]
\end{document}
```

## Output

The output I get contains the output of the original `\div` macro.

> [image: real]

## Expected Output

> [image: expected]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`unicode-math` does most of its work at `\begin{document}`, so you have to delay your declarations too:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}} % better than using \,\mathrm{d}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\div\relax
  \DeclareMathOperator{\div}{div}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\int_V \div \vec{F} \diff V = \oint_A \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} \diff A
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this is only needed because you want to override a command defined by `unicode-math`. Using `\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}` wouldn't need special precautions.

Comment: A little note: It only works if the `\AtBeginDocument{…}` block appears after `\usepackage{unicode-math}`. (Why?!)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `\diff` thing. BTW: What is the difference between `\let\x\undefined` and `\let\x\relax`?

Comment: @HenriMenke LaTeX executes code declared in `\AtBeginDocument` in order. If you issue it before loading `unicode-math` it would be the same situation as you had before. In general I recommend loading packages first and then adding code.

Comment: the `\diff` is a little farther from the `V` than it really needs to be.  `\mathrm{d}` by itself doesn't have that effect.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The output is exactly the same with `\,\mathrm{d}V` and `\diff V`: it's the same as in Henri's original picture. The leftmost serif of "V" is at the start of the rightmost serif of the "d". Of course the problem would not show with a proper italic "d". `;-)`

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\AtBeginDocument{
\let\div\undefined\DeclareMathOperator{\div}{div}
}
\begin{document}


\[ \int_V \div \vec{F} \, \mathrm{d}V = \oint_A \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} \, \mathrm{d}A \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which is great as well. Unfortunately I can accept only one.

Comment: @HenriMenke :-) http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9782116#9782116