# \nabla symbol missing when trying to redefine \div and \curl in unicode-math

Tags: macros, amsmath, unicode-math

I would like to redefine the `\div` and `\curl` commands to give `\mbfnabla\cdot` and `\mbfnabla\vectimes`.

In [unicode-math breaks \DeclareMathOperator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117990/unicode-math-breaks-declaremathoperator) we get the hint that we need to wrap redefines inside an `AtBeginDocument` block.
While this seems to work for redefining `\div` with just giving the text `div`, using `\nabla` or `\mbfnabla` does not render the respective nabla symbol:

[image: Maxwell equations with missing nabla symbols]

The corresponding MVP code is:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand{\vdot}{\cdot}
\newcommand{\vcross}{\vectimes}
\newcommand{\vb}[1]{\symbfup{#1}}
\newcommand{\vu}[1]{\hat{\vb{#1}}}

\AtBeginDocument{   
    \let\div\relax
    \let\curl\relax
    \DeclareMathOperator{\div}{\mbfnabla\vdot}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\curl}{\mbfnabla\vectimes}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \div\vb{E}
        &=
        j_0
        &
        \div\vb{B}
        &=
        0
        \\
        \curl\vb{E}
        &=
        -\partial_t\vb{B}
        &
        \curl\vb{B}
        &=
        \vb{j}
        +
        \partial_t\vb{E}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

I am using LuaLaTex on MacOS where I recently updated all packages with `tlmgr update -all`.

Comment: It’s a good practice to add `\tracinglostchars=3` near the top of your document, which tells TeX to treat bugs like this as errors.

Comment: I just had this issue come up, where the font I used contained `$\Delta$`, but not `$\nabla$`. I ended up using `$\sbox0{$\Delta$}\raisebox{\ht0}{\rotatebox{180}{$\Delta$}}$` as a replacement for `$\nabla$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be seen in the log file:

```
Missing character: There is no  (U+1D6C1) in font [lmroman10-regular]
```

You can use a similar math font that has the glyph:

```
documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}

\newcommand{\vdot}{\cdot}
\newcommand{\vcross}{\vectimes}
\newcommand{\vb}[1]{\symbfup{#1}}
\newcommand{\vu}[1]{\hat{\vb{#1}}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\div}{\mbfnabla\vdot}%
  \newcommand{\curl}{\mbfnabla\vectimes}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \div\vb{E}  &= j_0               & \div\vb{B}  &= 0
  \\
  \curl\vb{E} &= -\partial_t\vb{B} & \curl\vb{B} &= \vb{j} + \partial_t\vb{E}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You *might* use `\DeclareMathOperator`, but the spacing will be not the best.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}

\newcommand{\vdot}{\cdot}
\newcommand{\vcross}{\vectimes}
\newcommand{\vb}[1]{\symbfup{#1}}
\newcommand{\vu}[1]{\hat{\vb{#1}}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\div\relax
  \DeclareMathOperator{\div}{\mathnormal{\mbfnabla\vdot}}%
  \DeclareMathOperator{\curl}{\mathnormal{\mbfnabla\vectimes}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \div\vb{E}  &= j_0               & \div\vb{B}  &= 0
  \\
  \curl\vb{E} &= -\partial_t\vb{B} & \curl\vb{B} &= \vb{j} + \partial_t\vb{E}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But the definition can be, more simply,

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\div}{\mathop{\mbfnabla\vdot}}%
  \newcommand{\curl}{\mathop{\mbfnabla\vectimes}}%
}
```

Comment: for some reason using `setmathfont` alone did not work for me but adapting `renewcommand` and `newcommand` did! Would you generally advise for `newcommand` over `DeclareMathOperator`?

Comment: @bodokaiser In this particular case, you don't want an operator, or, as I showed, the spacings are all wrong.

Comment: Ah, I think the term "operator" in `DeclareMathOperator` should not be understood in a strict "mathematical" sense, e.g., differential operator. In the amsmath package docs `DeclareMathOperator` is used for `sin`, `lim`, `max`, i.e., functions and operations which are abbreviated with letters (not a single symbol!).

Comment: @bodokaiser Yes, it's more in TeX sense, as regards to the spacing.